# Active perspective is null if a view is detached

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

If I right click and detach a view, `modelService.getActivePerspective(window)` starts returning null. This means that resetting the perspective doesn't work correctly.

If a view isn't detached it works correctly. I'm thinking that as a new window is open it is passing a different window that doesn't contain the perspective.

**Example**

```
public class ResetPerspectiveHandler {
    @Execute
    public static void resetPerspective(final MApplication app, final EPartService partService,
        final EModelService modelService, final MWindow window) {

    // Prints null
    System.out.println(modelService.getActivePerspective(window));

    PerspectiveSnippetsCopier.resetPerspective(modelService, partService, app, window,
        modelService.getActivePerspective(window).getElementId());
    }
}
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `getActivePerspective` is:

```
public MPerspective getActivePerspective(MWindow window) {
    List<MPerspectiveStack> pStacks = findElements(window, null, MPerspectiveStack.class);
    if (pStacks.size() == 1) {
        MPerspective perspective = pStacks.get(0).getSelectedElement();
        return perspective;
    }

    return null;
}
```

So it expects to find a `MPerspectiveStack` in the given window, presumbly the detached window does not have this.

You could try finding the main window in the app rather than using the current window.

```
MWindow mainWindow = (MWindow)modelService.find("main window id", app);
```

Comment: This makes sense. I can successfully get the main window now and reset the perspective for it. The problem is that the detached views don't close as they are separate windows. How might I get all windows in the application? From that I can dispose all windows that aren't the main window. I can see how to get windows by id but not how to get all windows.

Comment: `modelService.findElements(app, null, MWindow.class)` will return a list of windows in the app.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that null could be passed in as the id. Thank you for the help as usual!